# Showing that a function is a modifying function (how to prove subadditivity)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

This is the definition of a modifying function I've got to work with:

> In this problem, a function $\phi :[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is called a modifying function if
>
> - (a) $\phi (0)=0$
> - (b) $\phi $ is strictly increasing
> - (c) $\phi$ is subadditive; i.e. $\phi (s+t) \leq \phi (s)+\phi (t)$ for all $s,t \in [0,\infty)$.

This is what I'm supposed to show:

> Show that if $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is a differentiable function such that
>
> - (i) $f(0)=0$
> - (ii) $f'$ is continuous, strictly positive and decreasing
>
> then $f$ is a modifying function.

(a) is satisfied by definition.

(b) is satisified because $f'$ is strictly positive.

(c) This is where I'm stuck. I feel like I should be able to prove it using some combination of the fact that $x\leq y \Leftrightarrow f(x)\leq f(y) \Leftrightarrow f'(x)\geq f'(y)$, but I'm not getting anywhere. Should I consider a different approach (and what approach would that be)?

(c.1) If I could prove that $f(tx)\geq tf(x)$ I would know how to prove it.

Comment: Note for $f(x)=\sqrt(x)$ that $f(tx)\ge tf(x)$ seems to be false when $t>1$. But it seems to hold if $t \le 1$. Does your "c.1" proof rely on $t \le 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H(s,t)=f(s)+f(t)-f(s+t)$ is increasing in both $s$ and $t$, since its partials are
$$H_s(s,t)=f'(s)-f'(s+t),\ \ H_t(s,t)=f'(t)-f'(s+t),$$ and also both $s<s+t$ and $t<s+t$, and the assumption is that $f'$ is decreasing. I think your desired result follows from this: Assume $s<t.$ Since $H(0,t)=0,$ as you increase the smaller variable from $0$ to $s$ the above remark on the partials shows $H$ will increase, forcing $H(s,t)\ge 0.$

Comment: What a nice solution. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

I am ten years late in answering, but here is another way to see this.

Consider $s+t > s \geq t > 0$.

If $t=0$, sub-additivity is obvious.

By MVT, $f(s+t) - f(s) = tf'(a), f(t) = f(t) - f(0) = tf'(b)$.

Note that $a \in (s, s+t), b \in (0, t)$ so $a > b$.
Hence $f'(a) \leq f'(b)$, implying sub-additivity.